# RoR multiple database connection in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku

My ruby on rails app contains two database connection and its working good in localhost, but its not working on heroku. Getting this error

`/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:52:in 'resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)`

database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: unicode
  database: first_database
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: unicode
  database: second_database
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

Since heroku overwrites default database.yml file, I followed this tutorial https://roratmindfiresolutions.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/connect-to-remote-database-server-from-heroku to setup multiple database connection on heroku, but still no change. I am using rails `4.0.1` . Any helps and suggestions are really appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in his YAML file he calls them `production` and `production_sec` whereas you're using `production` twice.